# Boost Python: Callback from c++ to python produces segmentation fault

Tags: boost-python

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the issue I'm having.
PyObject_Str, PyObject_Str, PyObject_CallObject produces a segmentation fault.

main.py:

```py
import core
def callback():
    print('callback called')

print(core.set_callback(callback))
```

core.cpp:

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void set_callback(PyObject *callback)
{
    //PyGILState_STATE state = PyGILState_Ensure(); // raises Fatal Python error: PyMUTEX_LOCK(_PyRuntime.ceval.gil.mutex) failed
    std::cout << PyObject_Hash(callback) << std::endl; //284906782
    std::cout << PyCallable_Check(callback) << std::endl; // 1
    //std::cout << PyObject_Str(callback) << std::endl; // segmentation fault
    //std::cout << PyObject_Repr(callback) << std::endl; // segmentation fault
    PyObject_CallObject(callback, NULL); // segmentation fault
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(core)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("set_callback", set_callback);
}
```

Comment: Works fine here without changing anything (didn't try uncommenting anyting)... although I'm curious why not use `boost::python::object` in `set_callback`.

Comment: Seems like more details would help. What platform, compiler, boost and Python versions? How did you obtain the boost binaries? How exactly did you build your pyd?

Comment: You are right, I tried compiling this in a linux box instead of my macos laptop and worked well.